# Random rubbish at the end of inBook citation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I have the following bibtex entry:

```
@InBook{bielecki2015,
  Title                    = {Conditional Markov chains -- construction and properties},
  Author                   = {Bielecki, Tomasz and Jakubowski, Jacek and Niew{\k{e}}g{\l}owski, Mariusz},
  Pages                    = {33–42},
  Year                     = {2015},

  Booktitle                = {Stochastic analysis. Special volume in honour of Jerzy Zabczyk},
  Owner                    = {ga},
  Timestamp                = {2016.09.04}
}
```

which I am trying to cite in my Horizon 2020 proposal - which means it goes into footnotes. I have the following things relevant to citations in my file:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
...
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize} % should correspond to 8pt
\renewcommand{\cite}{\textcite} % citations in footnotes
\bibliography{../../bib/all}  
....
\cite{bielecki2016}
```

and I am getting this footnote:

[image: footnote]

How can I remove the random characters at the end on the citation?

Comment: Looks like the dash character in `Pages = {33–42},` is a bit off, try and replace it with a normal ASCII dash `-`.

Comment: Page ranges in `biblatex` should have two dashes, as in `33--42`.

Comment: @Alenanno Not necessarily, `pages = {20-24}` should also be fine, Biber can parse that correctly (cf. `biblatex-examples.bib`).

Comment: @moewe I might have misread the documentation, then.

Comment: @Alenanno Where you are right is that page ranges in citation commands are currently not parsed (at least to my knowledge), so one would probably want to have `--` there instead of `-`.

Comment: @moewe, you were spot-on. Please paste your comment as answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dash character you have in

```
Pages                    = {33–42},
```

is dodgy (in fact it is `U+2013: EN DASH`), replace it with your ordinary dash `-` (`U+002D: HYPHEN-MINUS`) and we should be OK.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this must be common issue when copy-pasting bibtex contents from the browser.

Comment: @Grzenio Yes, there are quite some dash characters that look more or less (sometimes even exactly) like your normal dash, but aren't.